# Simplicial Cohomology (References and some questions)

Tags: homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex

May I ask for recommendations for references for the topic of simplicial cohomology?

Hatcher's book (Chapter 3, pg 186) does have some write up of simplicial cohomology, but just 2 to 3 pages.

Also, just to ask how do we view simplicial cohomology as a special case of cohomology of spaces? Is a $n$-simplex the same as a singular $n$-simplex $\sigma: \Delta^n\to\Delta^n$ where $\sigma$ is the identity?

Thanks.

Comment: Could it be that you mean with your last paragraph that SINGULAR cohomology is a special case of SIMPLICIAL cohomology? Because I don't think it's true the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chapter five of the book Elements of Algebraic Topology by Munkres deals with simplicial cohomology in great detail. He also studies homology in the book and relates (simplicial) cohomology to (simplicial) homology.